# Mono app on OSX - libfreetype.dylib issues

Tags: .net, macos, mono, freetype, gdi+

Hi I am new to mono development and was hoping to get some advice.

We are trying to develop GTK# 2.0 application with mono 2.10 working on Mac Snow Leoplard 10.6+. We are using a 3rd party .NET dll in our mono project on Mac. This 3rd party dll is referencing libgdiplus library which is later referencing libfreetype.dylib library located at /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.dylib (at least this location is shown in mono debug mode when running our app).

Currently we face 2 issues:

1) we get an error that libfreetype.dylib version is old, mono debug says there is 10.0 but it should be 13.0
Question is can we just overwrite that lib with new one in package installer on mac? We have copied libfreetype.dylib from X11 xquartz 2.6.0 and that solved this issue (just to clear things out installing xquartz 2.6.0 does not solve out issue, we still get that error).
Can we somehow add a reference to new libfreetype.dylib from mono project?

2) after manual update to libfreetype.dylib version 13.0 we get another error that /usr/share/fonts/ttf are missing, but there is no such folder in default X11 install, again we did a manual copy of fonts folder from xquartz 2.6.0 install, after that our application was working fine. 
Question is can we bundle fonts folder in the package installer and install it on mac without any issues?

Any help or clues would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and is being investigated:
http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=272

Sadly this is not the only issue wrt libgdiplus on OS X:
http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=273

You can use (see comments) the libgdiplus (and related libraries) from an older Mono (until new packages are available).